# SCP: file not found when trying to copy from windows to linux server

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, scp

In putty i want to copy a .war file from my machine (at `D:\\file.war`) to a remote server like this:

```
sudo scp -r D://file.war user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/tomcat8/webapps
```

it doesn`t work and i have also tried things like:

```
sudo scp -r \file.war user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/tomcat8/webapps
```

or

```
sudo scp -r /cygdrive/d/file.war user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/tomcat8/webapps
```

I have to type in my password two times then (one time for sudo, next time for user). But then i get always the same error:

```
<pathtolocalfile>: No such file or directory
```

Putty always connects via SSH. I need `sudo` to get permission to write into the webapps folder.

How do i have to specify the path? Sry, i´m trying this for the first time and after some research i´m getting more and more confused about how to do this the right way.

Comment: What's the error you get? Have you tried without sudo? Have you made sure your public key is on the remote server?

Comment: Hi @flixe what is the error? + can you do a `ssh` login to the distant machine?

Comment: So you are on the Windows machine. What's the deal with `sudo` on a Windows machine?!

Comment: Error message is just: `D://file.war: No such file or directory`. To deploy my file in the tomcat webapps directory i need root permission and my admin told me i would get them by just using "sudo". When i connect with putty, i always connect with type "SSH". @mohammedkhan what do you mean by public key? how can i check that?

Comment: You say you're running these commands in putty? So, you're running putty on the windows PC, using putty to log in to a linux system, and then running these commands within the putty session? Is that correct? This would mean you're actually running scp on the linux host.

Comment: yes, that is correct. But i thought that would be the correct way to copy the files. I also tried using Winscp to transfer the file, but there i don´t know how to handle the permission restriction of the webapps folder. So what would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do what i wanted, although my solution is not the nicest:

1. I connected to the server using WinSCP and my normal user account.
2. There i copied the file into my user home directory.
3. Then i opened the Putty console in WinSCP and changed to root user with "sudo" (and typing in my password again).
4. Now i finally was able to copy the file from my user accounts home directory into the webapps folder of tomcat.